# Custom PHP programming (not plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I apologize in advance, for what even I realize may be stupid question.

But I never worked with wordpress before, so what I want to do is create new page, have some custom HTML form in it, post the data to somewhere and then save it to database.

Can someone please point me to good tutorial about this? When I google I google anything post related, I mainly get results about.

I have no idea where to begin looking. 
Do I need to develop functionality like that with plugin? 
Some other way?

Comment: You want to create a page which asks the site visitor some questions and store that data to db? If so, how are you planning to access that data? Also from WP admin?

Comment: Sorry, I upvoted both, but was not sure which to accept as I found both useful :) Thanks for you help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Welcome to wordpress world…* Yes you can use templates … but also:

**Custom posts**, will you give all the freedom to do what you want:
 • [Custom post generator](https://generatewp.com/post-type/).
 • [Post types (on Wordpress Codex)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)

Extend your posts types with **Custom fields**
• [Adding custom fields](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64939/how-to-add-a-predefined-custom-field-without-using-a-plugin)
• Use the powerful [ACF plugin](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com)

Is better to work on a **child theme**. 
[Child Themes (on Wordpress Codex)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Why? Because when your theme is updated, you don't loose your code.

Once you have created and activated your child theme, you can:

- Add your code to the function.php file *(in your child theme)*
- Work and modifie the php files of your theme (copying them to the child theme), *without loosing anything when theme get updated*.
- Create and add some custom php files like templates…
- Work with **custom post**, **custom fields**…

Wordpress is very modular and open, so there is many ways to achieve a project.

*You can also create your own theme, or you can use some scalable and modular frameworks (Genesis Framework…)*

Answer (score 1):

All what you need to do is to make cusotm wordpress page template. In template you can insert any code you want and then just pick this template in page editor.

You can easly create custom page template in 4 steps

1. **Go to your wordpress installation via FTP**
2. **Go to `wp-content/themes/` and duplicate page.php file or any other page template file**
3. **Rename new file and add "template" key-word. For example: `page-template-mytemplate.php` . Remmember also to change template name inside particular file ( check out tutorials posted below or Documentation )**
4. **Create page and select your new Template from Template block**

Hope that helps.

Here you have some links: 
[Wordpress.org Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) 
[Detailed guide about wordpress custom page templates](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/06/wordpress-custom-page-templates/)
[Some YT vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9HCxKyj1SV0)